# Как заполнить массив?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Как заполнить одномерный массив, чтобы цифра в массиве соответствовала индексу.

Например:

`x: array [1..7] of integer;`

и чтобы под 1 было 1, под 5 - 5 и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

что то типа

```
 ...
 for k := 1 to 7 do
 x[k] := k;
 ...
```